# Can't send a single key function to remote desktop

Tags: c#, keyboard, desktop, sendinput

After a really deep drill down the web, this is my code which unfortunately doesnt send the keys as upper case :/

**MapVirtualKey Implementation:**

```
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC = 0x00;
    const uint MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK = 0x01;
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR = 0x02;
    const uint MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX = 0x03;
    const uint MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC_EX = 0x04;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MapVirtualKey(uint uCode, uint uMapType);
```

**SendInput Implementation:**

```
        struct INPUT
{
           public UInt32 Type;
           public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
```

}

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public KEYBDINPUT Keyboard;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public HARDWAREINPUT Hardware;
}


  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);
```

**Now for the methods:**

This method send keys as string, which work fine through the remote desktop:

```
        public static void SimulateTextEntry(string text)
    {
        if (text.Length > UInt32.MaxValue / 2) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The text parameter is too long. It must be less than {0} characters.", UInt32.MaxValue / 2), "text");

        var chars = UTF8Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        var len = chars.Length;
        INPUT[] inputList = new INPUT[len * 2];
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
        {
            UInt16 scanCode = chars[x];

            var down = new INPUT();
            down.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
            down.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
            down.Data.Keyboard.Vk = 0;
            down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = scanCode;
            down.Data.Keyboard.Flags = (UInt32)KeyboardFlag.UNICODE;
            down.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
            down.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

            var up = new INPUT();
            up.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
            up.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
            up.Data.Keyboard.Vk = 0;
            up.Data.Keyboard.Scan = scanCode;
            up.Data.Keyboard.Flags = (UInt32)(KeyboardFlag.KEYUP | KeyboardFlag.UNICODE);
            up.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
            up.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

            // Handle extended keys:
            // If the scan code is preceded by a prefix byte that has the value 0xE0 (224),
            // we need to include the KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY flag in the Flags property. 
            if ((scanCode & 0xFF00) == 0xE000)
            {
                down.Data.Keyboard.Flags |= (UInt32)KeyboardFlag.EXTENDEDKEY;
                up.Data.Keyboard.Flags |= (UInt32)KeyboardFlag.EXTENDEDKEY;
            }

            inputList[2*x] = down;
            inputList[2*x + 1] = up;

        }

        var numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs = SendInput((UInt32)len*2, inputList, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
    }
```

**this method is used to press down a key, its originally set to:**

```
    down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = 0;
```

**but i tried to use the mapvirtualkey so notice the change:**

```
KeyPress:

  public static void SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode keyCode)
    {
        var down = new INPUT();
        down.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
        down.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        down.Data.Keyboard.Vk = (UInt16)keyCode;
       // down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = 0;
        ushort mapvirtualkeyresult = (ushort)(MapVirtualKey((UInt16)keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR));
        down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = mapvirtualkeyresult;
        down.Data.Keyboard.Flags = 0;
        down.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
        down.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        var up = new INPUT();
        up.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
        up.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        up.Data.Keyboard.Vk = (UInt16)keyCode;
        //up.Data.Keyboard.Scan = 0;
        up.Data.Keyboard.Scan = (ushort)(MapVirtualKey((UInt16)keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR));
        up.Data.Keyboard.Flags = (UInt32)KeyboardFlag.KEYUP;
        up.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
        up.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        INPUT[] inputList = new INPUT[2];
        inputList[0] = down;
        inputList[1] = up;

        var numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs = SendInput(2, inputList, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        if (numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("The key press simulation for {0} was not successful.", keyCode));
    }
```

**KeyDown:**

```
     public static void SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode keyCode)
    {
        var down = new INPUT();
        down.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
        down.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        down.Data.Keyboard.Vk = (UInt16)keyCode;
        down.Data.Keyboard.Scan = (ushort)(MapVirtualKey((UInt16)keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR));
        down.Data.Keyboard.Flags = 0;
        down.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
        down.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        INPUT[] inputList = new INPUT[1];
        inputList[0] = down;

        var numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs = SendInput(1, inputList, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        if (numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("The key down simulation for {0} was not successful.", keyCode));
    }
```

**KeyUp:**

```
  public static void SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode keyCode)
    {
        var up = new INPUT();
        up.Type = (UInt32)InputType.KEYBOARD;
        up.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT();
        up.Data.Keyboard.Vk = (UInt16)keyCode;
        up.Data.Keyboard.Scan = (ushort)(MapVirtualKey((UInt16)keyCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR));
        up.Data.Keyboard.Flags = (UInt32)KeyboardFlag.KEYUP;
        up.Data.Keyboard.Time = 0;
        up.Data.Keyboard.ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

        INPUT[] inputList = new INPUT[1];
        inputList[0] = up;

        var numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs = SendInput(1, inputList, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
        if (numberOfSuccessfulSimulatedInputs == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("The key up simulation for {0} was not successful.", keyCode));
    }
```

**And for the testing:**

```
     int i=0;
           while (i<10)
           {
               Thread.Sleep(5000);
               InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("text");
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_B);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.LSHIFT);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_B);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
               InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.LSHIFT);
               i++;
           }
```

on my console window i see:
textabcABC
textabcABC
etc...

on the rdc console window all i see is:
text
text
etc...

as if the single key press doesnt work!

Will Much appreciate any help!
thanks ahead,
Niv.

Comment: I'm really trying to help you there but I need an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).
I see there an solution for your problem but can´t help with uncompilable code.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of RunAsUser / CreateProcessAsUser

Comment: What is the point of checking "text.Length > UInt32.MaxValue / 2"? It is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Y not to use simple System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("textabc") it will work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mapping to key codes, you should just send the characters directly using the `KEYEVENTF_UNICODE` flag.  Not all characters are representable as Virtual Keys.

Sending a `LSHIFT` does not cause the keyboard state to get updated, so when the target checks whether shift is depressed, the actual state of the keyboard is used.

Based off of your `input.Data.Keyboard.Scan = 0` line, at one time, it was using the appropriate message.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        #region P/Invokes

        struct INPUT
        {
            public INPUTType type;
            public INPUTUnion Event;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
        struct INPUTUnion
        {
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal MOUSEINPUT mi;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal KEYBDINPUT ki;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            internal HARDWAREINPUT hi;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct MOUSEINPUT
        {
            public int dx;
            public int dy;
            public int mouseData;
            public int dwFlags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KEYBDINPUT
        {
            public short wVk;
            public short wScan;
            public KEYEVENTF dwFlags;
            public int time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct HARDWAREINPUT
        {
            public int uMsg;
            public short wParamL;
            public short wParamH;
        }

        enum INPUTType : uint
        {
            INPUT_KEYBOARD = 1
        }

        [Flags]
        enum KEYEVENTF : uint
        {
            EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001,
            KEYUP = 0x0002,
            SCANCODE = 0x0008,
            UNICODE = 0x0004
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern UInt32 SendInput(int numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, int sizeOfInputStructure);

        private static void Send(string s)
        {
            foreach (var c in s)
                Send(c);
        }

        private static void Send(char c)
        {
            SendKeyInternal((short)c);
        }

        #endregion

        private static void SendKeyInternal(short key)
        {
            // create input events as unicode with first down, then up
            INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[2];
            inputs[0].type = inputs[1].type = INPUTType.INPUT_KEYBOARD;
            inputs[0].Event.ki.dwFlags = inputs[1].Event.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF.UNICODE;
            inputs[0].Event.ki.wScan = inputs[1].Event.ki.wScan = key;    
            inputs[1].Event.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;

            uint cSuccess = SendInput(inputs.Length, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
            if (cSuccess != inputs.Length)
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            Send("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```